# Progress bar in Python for varying loops

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, progress-bar

I'm assuming this can't be done easily but atm I've written for loops in python that take in multiple files from a folder and runs them against an executable to convert them into a readable format. Problem is, the number of files will be different almost every time I run the script. The whole process takes a while so a progress bar would be nice. I've been trying tqdm, progress, etc. modules, but they all seem to work based on a fixed number of iterations, which doesn't work for me.

Basically, is there any possible way to easily implement a progress bar which either calculates progress based on how long the process will take to perform the conversions, or based on how many there are to convert?

Though having said this, for one part of the code, instead of taking in files, it was easier to run a powershell script in cmd through python to keep it part of the same code. This script iterates through many many files and outputs 1 file. Again, is there a way to monitor the progress of this in python, even though in python the code is just running something in cmd?

Comment: It sounds like you just need to know how many files you will be looping through before the script stars the loop.  If this is the case you could use os.listdir() to get the file count before running the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try PyProg! PyProg is an open-source library for Python to create super customizable progress indicators & bars.

It is currently at version 1.0.2; it is hosted on Github and available on PyPI (Links down below). It is compatible with Python 3 and 2.

I actually made PyProg because I needed a simple but super customizable progress bar library. And I made it super flexible as well, so you can use `set_total(<total>)` to set the total number of files you need to convert and use `set_stat(<status>)` to set the current progress, and it will calculate the percentage for you!

You can easily install it with: `pip install pyprog`. Some examples of using it is on the Github page for this project.

PyProg Github: https://github.com/Bill13579/pyprog
PyPI: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyprog/